# How to shove this loop into numpy?

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop, numpy

I have a slow loop that I want to make (much) faster by pushing it into numpy. I have spent days playing with this code without getting anywhere. Is it even possible, or is there a numpy trick I am missing? Is there some refactoring I can do to help?

As you can see, I want to sum the mixins as shifted by the xs.

```
import numpy as np

blocksize = 1000 # Chosen at runtime.
mixinsize = 100 # Chosen at runtime.
count = 10000 # Chosen at runtime.
xs = np.random.randint(0, blocksize + 1, count) # In practice this is data.
mixins = np.empty((count, mixinsize)) # In practice this is data.

# The slow part:
accumulator = np.zeros(blocksize + mixinsize)
for i in xrange(count):
    accumulator[xs[i]:xs[i] + mixinsize] += mixins[i]
```

### Comments on accepted answer

- To get numba to work, I first had to ensure I was using appropriate numpy types everywhere, and certainly not ordinary python types. This by itself was a huge performance improvement.
- Numba improved the specific case of speed as count got large, which is what i wanted (perhaps I should have highlighted that in the question).
- Different numba versions have significantly different timings in my current testcase, but I think numba is a great idea with lots of potential and it's being actively developed so i'll stick with it.
- Use anaconda to install numba, in particular it makes it easy to switch between numba versions.

Comment: Can you show an example with the first few elements of the data and desired result  ?

Comment: I see no obvious way to do what you want. You should get better results using Cython, and you could code cython solution to this in an afternoon.

Comment: @wwii You can fiddle with the blocksize/mixinsize/count and come up with xs/mixins within the above constraints, then the desired result is the accumulator as calculated by "the slow part". I have done this myself but I think the numbers are more of a distraction than useful so I have not added them to the question. I'm interested in any solution that replaces "the slow part" and given the same xs/mixins returns the same accumulator.

Comment: @jb. Thanks, Cython looks good and I will investigate it if no one can come up with a numpy solution. I am particularly interested in a numpy solution as one of the goals of my project is to push python/numpy to the limit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get Numba 0.11 (not 0.12 yet) from numba.pydata.org. Now we can jit compile this code with LLVM:

```
# plain NumPy version
import numpy as np

def foobar(mixinsize, count, xs, mixins, acc):
    for i in xrange(count):
        k = xs[i]
        acc[k:k + mixinsize] += mixins[i,:]


# LLVM compiled version
from numba import jit, void, int64, double
signature = void(int64,int64,int64[:],double[:,:],double[:])
foobar_jit = jit(signature)(foobar)
```

---

```
if __name__ == "__main__":   
    from time import clock

    blocksize = 1000 # Chosen at runtime.
    mixinsize = 100 # Chosen at runtime.
    count = 100000 # Chosen at runtime. 
    xs = np.random.randint(0, blocksize + 1, count)
    mixins = np.empty((count, mixinsize))
    acc = np.zeros(blocksize + mixinsize)

    t0 = clock()
    foobar(mixinsize, count, xs, mixins, acc)
    t1 = clock()
    print("elapsed time: %g ms" % (1000*(t1-t0),))

    t2 = clock()
    foobar_jit(mixinsize, count, xs, mixins, acc)
    t3 = clock()
    print("elapsed time with numba jit: %g ms" % (1000*(t3-t2),))

    print("speedup factor: %g" % ((t1-t0)/(t3-t2),))
```

---

```
$ python test_numba.py
elapsed time: 590.632 ms
elapsed time with numba jit: 12.31 ms
speedup factor: 47.9799
```

---

Ok, so that is almost 50x speedup with just three additional lines of Python code.

Now we can also test a plain C version for comparison, using clang/LLVM as compiler.

---

```
void foobar(long mixinsize, long count, 
    long *xs, double *mixins, double *accumulator)
{
    long i, j, k;
    double *cur, *acc;   
    for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
        acc = accumulator + xs[i];
        cur = mixins + i*mixinsize;
        for(j=0;j<mixinsize;j++) *acc++ += *cur++;
    }
}
```

---

```
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import ctypes
so = ctypes.CDLL('plainc.so')
foobar_c = so.foobar
foobar_c.restype = None
foobar_c.argtypes = (
    ctypes.c_long,
    ctypes.c_long,
    ndpointer(dtype=np.int64, ndim=1),
    ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=2),
    ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=1)
)


t4 = clock()
foobar_c(mixinsize, count, xs, mixins, acc)
t5 = clock()
print("elapsed time with plain C: %g ms" % (1000*(t5-t4),))
```

---

```
$ CC -Ofast -shared -m64 -o plainc.so plainc.c
$ python test_numba.py
elapsed time: 599.136 ms
elapsed time with numba jit: 11.958 ms
speedup factor: 50.1034
elapsed time with plain C: 5.472 ms
```

---

So, Numba is about half as fast as the plain C version when optimized with -Ofast. In comparison, the run-time using -O2 was about 8 ms. That means that the speed of Numba JIT compiled Python in this case is about 75 % of C with -O2 optimization flag. That is not bad for just three additional lines of Python code.

We can for comparison look at a plain Python version:

```
def foobar_py(mixinsize, count, xs, mixins, acc):
    for i in xrange(count):
        k = xs[i]
        for j in xrange(mixinsize):
            acc[j+k] += mixins[i][j]


# covert NumPy arrays to lists
_xs = map(int,xs)
_mixins = [map(float,mixins[i,:]) for i in xrange(count)]
_acc = map(float,acc)


t6 = clock()
foobar_py(mixinsize, count, _xs, _mixins, _acc)
t7 = clock()
print("elapsed time with plain Python: %g ms" % (1000*(t7-t6),))
```

This Python code executed in 1775 ms. Thus, relative to plain Python we could get about 3x speedup using NumPy, 150x speedup using Numba, and 350x speedup using C and -Ofast.

**A word of caution** from Donald Knuth, who attributed this to C. A. R. Hoare: *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil in computer programming."* While this might seem to be impressive relative speedups, the absolute speedup from going down this route only allowed us to save some milliseconds of CPU time. Was it really worth *my time* to save the CPU from that amount of labour? Is it worth *your* time? Decide for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I am excited about the Numba approach and will evaluate it when I next get a chance.

Re word of caution, I want to optimise this particular loop because it appears at the top of cProfile and so is the likely cause of user-visible slowness as count goes up. So it probably is worth your time.

Comment: User-visible slowness is a valid reason for optmization, just wanting to save a few milliseconds is not. Unfortunately, most who complain about Python's "slowness" want the latter. But then it is important to realize that a few milliseconds are below the limit of human perception, in case of a UI event handler. And for other parts of a program, using C will never give us a faster disk or a faster network connection. So actually profiling the code is always a good idea. :-)